# Send and get back data with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So basically I use an Ajax Script to insert data into my database, but
when I post the data which I have to use in the same file without reload, it is executed but nothing happens in the file, just the database insert is completed.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input#sbm").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            //url: '', // url is empty because I'm working in the same file
            data: $('form#ddb').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                alert("<?php echo "https://example.com/".$id; ?>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to echo out the link, but there is no $id set, but the database entry is made so it works ! So how can I use the php code in the file without reload, or is there any possible way to get data back from the file I send it too cause I defnitely need the $id variable on my page btw it is https://viid.su

```
if(isset($user["id"]))
{
   $uid = $user["id"];
}
else {
$uid = 0; 
}
  $flink = $_POST['url'];

    $re = '/^(?:https?\:\/\/)?[a-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-z0-9\-_\.\/%&=\?\+]+$/mi';
    $re2 = '/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i';
    if (!preg_match($re2, $flink, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0)){
    $flink = "http://". $flink; }

  if(preg_match($re, $flink, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0)){
        $db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

      $id = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxYyYzZ", 5)), 0, 5);
      if($conn->query("INSERT INTO `".$database."`.`link` (`id`, `flink`,`adonly`,`userid`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$flink."','true','".$uid."');")) {
        $html = 'Your short URL is <a class="test" href="https://viid.su/'.$id.'">https://viid.su/'.$id.'</a>';
         echo $html;
      } else {
      }
      mysqli_close($db);
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['url'])){
              $html = "THAT'S AN INVALID URL!";
  }
```

The php code is just for testing, I know there are a lot of things I have to do and edit, but I still want you all just to help me out with the problem I described :)

Comment: try alert(result); and post what result also

Comment: nope doesnt work

Comment: i asked to type result here

Comment: ah the result is the code of the page

Comment: We would need to see the code that handles this post request. You can't just echo `$id` if you haven#t defined it before. If your ID is defined in the Post handler then you need to send it inside the result itself. Inside a json object and access it like `result['id']` or as a direct value and just use `result` as your id. But without the actiual handler, I can't say more.

Comment: I added the php code

Comment: what is your desired output?be clear.